# nested for loop too slow: 1MN record traversal

Tags: unix

I've huge file count, around 200,000 records in a file. I have been testing some cases where in I have to figure out the naming pattern of the files match to some specific strings. Here's how I preceded-

Test Strings, I stored in a file (let's say for one case, they are 10). The actual file that contains string records, separated by newline; totaling upto 200,000 records. To check if the test string patterns are present in the large file, I wrote a small nested for loop.

```
for i in `cat TestString.txt`
do
for j in `cat LargeFile.txt`
do
if [[ $i == $j ]]
then
echo "Match" >> result.txt
fi
done
done
```

This nested loop actual has to do the traversal (if I'm not wrong in the concepts), 10x200000 times. Normally I don't see that's too much of a load on the server, but the time taken is like all along. The excerpt is running for the past 4 hours, with ofcourse some "matched" results.

Does anyone has any idea on speeding this up? I've found so many answers with python or perl touch, but I'm honestly searching for something in Unix.

Thanks

Comment: Your current code reads one word per loop. When the 10 records in TestString.txt have 20 words each, you will loop through the LargeFile.txt 10x20x200.000 times. How often do you check? When the LargeFile.txt also has 20 words for each record, you have 10x20x200.000x20 comparisons.

Comment: You should move `>> result.txt` outside the loops, so you will not close and open the file for each loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
grep -f TestString.txt LargeFile.txt >> result.txt
```

Comment: I always overlook the power of grep. Perfect solution. Thanks Walter.

Comment: @knowone: When you are happy wth this answer, you can accept it.

Comment: Done. Apologies, I should've done it back then itself.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `grep`

```
while read line
do
  cat LargeFile.txt | grep "$line" >> result.txt
done < TestString.txt
```

grep will output any matching strings. This may be faster. Note that your TestString.txt file should not have any blank lines or grep will return everything from LargeFile.txt.

Comment: grep is all I didn't took seriously :)
Worked fine with this approach as well. Thanks cantelope.